# How can I test my apps on a physical device?

Tags: android, emulation, android-sdk-tools

I want to test my apps on my physical android device. I have installed the drivers and this is a picture from device manager:

[image]

But it is not recognised by eclipse and when i write `adb -d devices` in cmd it shows just

```
List of devices attached
```

and nothing else...

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging? What device are you using? What version of Android?

Comment: yes.. this one http://www.serioux.com/products/ebook-reader/s101tab

Answer (score 0):

There are some additional steps to take after installing the USB driver, which I supposed you took from your SDK (for example: [Android SDK Root]\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver).

Additional to that you have to modify the file android_winusb.inf by appending similar lines to the sections [Google.NTx86] and [Google.NTamd64], lines that should be provided with the platform you're using.

Also you have to create/modify the C:\Users\.android\adb_usb.ini to contain a vendor ID provided also with the platform you're using. 

You can check out this Q&A for more details: [USB debugging - Issue with installing drivers for Epson Moverio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183634/usb-debugging-issue-with-installing-drivers)